# reload html table data after database entry deleted

Tags: asp-classic

I am building a web page using asp classic and populating a mdb into an html with delete button at the end of each row. When the delete button is clicked the database entry is being deleted, but the html table is not reloading and reflecting the data change. How can I make that happen when the delete button is clicked? Here is my code:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<% Option Explicit %>

<!--#include virtual="/adovbs.inc"-->

<HTML>
<%
        Dim objConn
        Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        objConn.ConnectionString="DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" & "DBQ=C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Scott1\EmployeeDB.mdb"

        objConn.Open

        Dim objRS
        Set objRS = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.RecordSet")

        objRS.Open "Employee", objConn, , adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

%>
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="default.asp">
<TABLE>

    <tr><td>First Name:</td><td><INPUT TYPE=INPUT NAME="FirstName"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><INPUT TYPE=INPUT NAME="LastName"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Employee ID:</td><td><INPUT TYPE=INPUT NAME="EmployeeID"></td></tr>
    <TR><TD><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME=ADD VALUE="Add"></td></tr>
<%
    objRS.AddNew
    objRS("FirstName") = Request.Form("FirstName")
    objRS("LastName") = Request.Form("LastName")
    objRS("EmployeeID") = Request.Form("EmployeeID")
    objRS.Update
%>

</TABLE>
</FORM>


<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="default.asp">
<TABLE BORDER=2 WIDTH=500>

    <TR BGCOLOR='#f8f8f8'>
        <TD>First Name</TD>
        <TD>Last Name</TD>
        <TD>Employee ID</TD>
        <TD>Delete</TD>
    </TR>

<%

    Do While Not objRS.EOF

        Response.Write "<TR><TD>" & objRS("FirstName") & "</TD>"
        Response.Write "<TD>" & objRS("LastName") & "</TD>"
        Response.Write "<TD>" & objRS("EmployeeID") & "</TD>"
        Response.Write "<TD><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME=Delete VALUE=Delete >" & objRS.Delete & "</TD></TR>"

        objRS.MoveNext

    Loop

    objRS.Close
    Set objRS = Nothing
    objConn.Close
    Set objConn = Nothing

%>

</table>


</FORM>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to give each `<tr>` an id based on the id of the current record then use JavaScript to post to the delete routine (which will be held in a separate ASP file), then hide the row by changing the `style.display`.

```
<tr id="row<%= rs("recordId") %>>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Delete" OnClick="deleteRow(<%= rs("recordId") %>);"
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the JavaScript could be something like...

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari...
else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");      // code for IE6, IE5

function ajaxPage(postPage, paramList) {xmlhttp.open("POST",postPage,false);xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");xmlhttp.send(paramList);return xmlhttp.responseText;}

function deleteRow(id) {
    ajaxPage("deleteFunctionPage.asp", "id=" + id);
    document.getElementById("row" + id).style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Perfect....thanks! I will see what I can do with this, but it seems to have answered my question perfectly. Thanks, again!